# How can one download the outputs of historical Azure ML experiment Runs via the python API

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to write a script which can download the outputs from an Azure ML experiment Run after the fact.

Essentially, I want to know how I can get a Run by its `runId` property (or some other identifier).

I am aware that I have access to the Run object when I create it for the purposes of training. What I want is a way to recreate this Run object later in a separate script, possibly from a completely different environment.

What I've found so far is a way to get a list of ScriptRun objects from an experiment via the `get_runs()` function. But I don't see a way to use one of these ScriptRun objects to create a Run object representing the original Run and allowing me to download the outputs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: clearly and succinctly asked question and your first question as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that this could probably be better documented, but fortunately, it's a simple implementation.

this is how you get a run object for an already submitted run for `azureml-sdk>=1.16.0` (for the older approach [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949488/amls-experiment-run-stuck-in-status-running/62958369#62958369))

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()
run = ws.get_run('YOUR_RUN_ID')
```

once you have the `run` object, you can call methods like

- `.get_file_names()` to see what files are available (the logs in `azureml-logs/` and `logs/azureml/` will also be listed)
- `.download_file()` to download an individual file
- `.download_files()` to download all files that match a given prefix (or all the files)

See the [Run object docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Anders, that worked a treat. I appreciate the swift response.
I guess I was too focused on the apparent nesting of ws -> experiment -> run to think of looking in workspace directly. I think skipping that nesting layer will help me find a few more things I've been looking for too. Thanks again

Comment: yeah the new `get_run` workspace method is snazzy for sure. heads up though that its a whole new ball game when you're passing data between steps of a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you both, just got a task to load traning results to some place else, never used the SDK before (or Azure ML in general), this is what I needed :)